# Novl from the 80s where humanity is wiped out by aliens, and a group of surviving children search for survivors

Tags: story-identification, novel

Back in the 80's, I read a novel about a girl named Jamie whose father was a maintenance worker for an underground bunker reserved for important people (president, Congress, scientists, etc) should there be a catastrophe (nuclear winter, etc).

Earth had made contact with an alien planet and was engaged in a territorial dispute over a planet both groups wanted to colonize. Jamie and her younger brother accompany her father on one of the routine facility checks of the bunker, and while they're there, the alien group attacks Earth and wipes out human beings.

Jamie, her brother, and her father seem to be the only people left on Earth. Dad spirals into a deep depression, Jamie and her brother manage by riding the quad vehicles through the corridors of the facility, eating canned peaches, and using the radio communications system in the bunker -- ultimately it's up to the kids to keep up the search for survivors.

They make contact with some people who were in a submarine at the time of the attack, and they begin to realize that anyone who was underground or underwater (deep) at the time of the attack would have survived. They get dad out of bed with this information, and ultimately they begin contacting others.

There's an epilogue in the book in which Jamie's great-granddaughter is living once again above ground, rebuilding human society.

I really liked this book, but I do not remember the title or the author.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268281/a-post-apocalyptic-story-about-a-father-and-daughter-who-survive-an-alien-attack (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

*[Strange Tomorrow](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/jean-e-karl/strange-tomorrow/)* by Jean Karl. 1985.

> This fleshes out the Clordian Sweep alluded to in Karl's The Turning Place (1976) and But We Are Not of Earth (1981). The first half deals with 13-year-old "Janie One," who, through unlikely circumstances, finds herself, her Air Force captain father, and her younger brother in an underground Presidential bunker when an attack from the planet Clord destroys all exposed life on earth--grass, trees, everything. Then, while their father lies in bed in a deep depression, the two children establish radio communication with a few other survivors. Part two, set generations later, takes up "Janie Two," a novice Sustainer setting off from her home cave as part of a program to populate different valleys according to the plans and seed supplies of the earlier Janie's "wiser" generation.